# Ramsey coloring of $K_{13}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> Arrange the vertices of $K_{13}$ in such a way that they form a regular $13$-gon. Color the edges (which are now either edges or diagonals of the 13-gon) in read and blue, where an edge is colored red if and only if it is either an edge of the $13$-gon or a diagonal such that 4 vertices lie on one of the its sides and 7 vertices on the other side. Use this coloring to show that $R(3,5) \geq 14$. Then use the lemma showing bounds for the Ramsey numbers to prove that $R(3,5) = 14$.

Any ideas? I'm already having difficulty imaging the situation and the problem.

Comment: @bof I posted the problem as it is stated. So, as long as I understood it asks for a coloring, which as you said is the $R(3,5)\ge14$ part. Then, it somehow asks to use the lemma to to show that $R(3,5) = 14$.

Comment: Well, the only lemma that we studied is $R(r,s) \leq R(r-1,s) + R(r,s-1)$. It simply doesn't tell which lemma to use, but as I said this is the only one that I found.

Comment: Right. Putting $r=3$ and $s=5$ in that lemma gives us the upper bound $R(3,5)\le R(2,5)+R(3,4).$ Do you know the values of $R(2,5)$ and $R(3,4)$?

Comment: $R(2,5) = 5$, $R(3,4) = 9$, so we have $R(3,5) = 14$, which $R(3,5) \geq 14$ clearly hold.

Comment: Yeah, I mistyped the direction of the sign. Well, that was my problem to actually transform $K_{13}$ as a regular 13-gon and color it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inequality lemma you have already proved that $R(3,5) \leq 14$, so if you find a red-blue coloring for $k_{13}$  such that there is no red $k_
3$ and no blue $k_5$ you would have proven that $R(3,5) > 13$ which means that $R(3,5)=14$

The required coloring is described in your exercise:

> An edge is colored red if and only if it is either an edge of the 13-gon or a diagonal such that 4 vertices lie on one of its sides and 7 vertices on the other side

and of course the rest is blue.

so first you draw the red 13-gon and then you add from each vertex a diagonal such that it has 4 vertices on one side and 7 on the other. Something like this:

[image]

finally you get :

[image]

this is the red edges in the coloring and which they do not contain a $k_3$

now you continue your coloring, by connecting each vertex to the remaining 10 vertices with the color blue, which will also not contain a blue $k_5$

One note though: if your textbook have not proved that $R(3,4)=9$ before, then you are required to, and this can be done using the same idea:

1. first use the lemma and you get $R(3,4) \leq R(2,4)+R(3,3)=4+6=10$
2. find a red-blue coloring for $k_8$ such that there is no red $k_3$ nor a blue $k_4$
3. prove that there is always in a red-blue coloring of $k_9$ either a red $k_3$ or a blue $k_4$

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm having difficulty imagining that coloring. It seems kind of complex to me.

Comment: this edit might help